# Using ArcGIS Desktop on a remote desktop server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-license-manager

We have about 5 users, they will user ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 by connecting to a Server through Remote Desktop Connection. ArcGIS Desktop obtain licence from a licence manager on anther server.

If the 5 users working at the same (Remotely from same Server), how many licences on Licence manager will be used?
Are the licences are per IP or per user?

**Adding one more point**

How I can give the users different type of licences? Example one will have Advanced and other will have Editor, etc..
We tried to experiment this, If licence changed for one user it will change for all other user.

Comment: how are they logging in to the remote server? eg, using individual Windows logins?

Comment: Server connected to domain, and every one have his own domain user not windows login

Comment: This is really a question for Esri.  Even if you can run 5 users on a single node, the performance of that node will depend on the load across all users.

Comment: Performance her dose not matter, mainly we need to understand how Licence manager will behave regarding the connected users

Comment: The license is consumed by a username/IP pair.. two users on the same workstation consume two licenses, one user on two workstations consume two licenses. If, however, you can somehow have multiple logons with the same credentials on the same workstation (not possible as I understand OS restrictions but something like VNC might be able to do it) then you might only use one license.

Answer (score 6):

My organisation operates in a similar setup.  We have found that licenses are assigned to each user/connection, so each user would get a separate license.

Opening extra sessions for each user will not consume extra licenses, but if they open a session on a different connection (still with their same user) will consume an extra license.

---

Regarding your extra comment about assigning specific types of licenses to users - this is done from each login using the ArcGIS Administrator (Start > Programs > ArcGIS > ArcGIS Administrator) and selecting Desktop in the left-hand section.  You can then select the relevant license type in the section on the right.  Admin access is required to run the ArcGIS Administrator.

Comment: I didn't get the Point. What you mean opening extra session?

Comment: @ayman - Opening another ArcMap on the same connection and use won't use another license.  Opening another ArcMap on a different connection will consume another license.

Comment: @ayman I have added info about selecting different licenses

Comment: Thanx Midavalo 
     The problem here, when one user change the licence type it will be changed for all users. Example if one have ArcInfo licence and other change his licence type to Editor, the first one licence type will automatically change to editor. How to solve this

Comment: You will need to talk to Esri